# cordova/phonegap - how to write in Isolated Storage, Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

Porting my app from android to WP8, I am writing/reading using cordova's API in **//myDir/MyFile.html**

Here my javascript code:

```
function writeOnFileSystem() {   
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(
                "/", onSuccess,
                onError);
}

function onSuccess(entry) { 
    entry.getDirectory("myDir", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
 }

function onError(error) {
    console.log("onError ...");
}

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
     dir.getFile("myFile.html", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

...

function readFile() {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
            "//MyDir/myFile.html", gotFSRead,
            onErrorRead);
}
```

- What is the path for writing in my app's Isolated Storage?

Comment: too many questions with no answer if it's about windows phone and cordova at the same time